# Basic help on def fxn in python

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

I am new to python and looked at the info here, but I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. I don't get an error and the #info outputs 27.75 which is what I want, but I'm trying to use 'def':

```
with open ('/Users/files') as f: 
           fasta = f.read()
           print (fasta) 

    #gc_count = fasta.count("G") + fasta.count("C")
    #gc_fraction = float(gc_count) / len(fasta)
    #100 * gc_fraction  
    
def GC(fasta): 
        gc = sum(fasta.count(x) for x in["G","C"])
        return gc * 100.0 / len(fasta)
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Move your def function above your main code

Comment: Merely defining a function has no effect.  You have to actually call the function - `print(GC(fasta))` perhaps.